# Find the sum of all primes smaller than a big number

Tags: number-theory, computational-complexity

I need to write a program that calculates the sum of all primes smaller than a given number $N$
($10^{10} \leq N \leq 10^{14} $).

Obviously, the program should run in a reasonable time, so $O(N)$ is not good enough.
I think I should find the sum of all the composite numbers smaller than $N$ and subtract it from $1+2+...+N$, but I'm trying that for a long time with no progress.

Comment: note that in order to say a number $x$ is prime you can run till $\sqrt{x}$

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the distribution of primes is $O(log(N))$, so your running time should be similar.

Comment: But how can I find all the primes in the first place in a sublinear time?

Comment: "I think I should find the sum of all the composite numbers smaller than $N$ and subtract it" <- This! A composite $\leqslant N$ has a smallest prime divisor $\leqslant \sqrt{N}$. Use inclusion-exclusion. (The Möbius function may be helpful.) Gets you $O(\sqrt{N})$ if I haven't overlooked anything.

Comment: Find something without searching?!

Comment: @DanielFischer - I tried to use inclusion-exclusion, but I still can't figure this out. The only method that pop in my mind is this:  
Let's say that the sum of all numbers bellow $N$ so that $k$ is their smallest divisor is $F(k)$. Let $S(k)$ be the sum of all multiples of $k$ bellow $N$.  
So, for example:   
$F(5) = S(5) - S(3*5) - S(2*5) + S(2*3*5)$.    
Finding $F(k)$ this way is $O(2^k)$. What am I missing?

Answer (score 6):

[Lucy_Hedgehog's post on Project Euler forum about problem 10](https://projecteuler.net/thread=10;page=5) (visible after logging in):

> Here is a solution that is more efficient than the sieve of
>   Eratosthenes. It is derived from similar algorithms for [counting
>   primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function). The advantage is that there is no need to find all the primes
>   to find their sum.
>
> The main idea is as follows: Let $S(v,m)$ be the sum of integers in the
>   range $2..v$ that remain after sieving with all primes smaller or equal
>   than m. That is $S(v,m)$ is the sum of integers up to $v$ that are either prime or the product of primes larger than $m$.
>
> $S(v, p)$ is equal to $S(v, p-1)$ if $p$ is not prime or $v$ is smaller than $p \cdot p$.
>   Otherwise ($p$ prime, $p \cdot p \leq v$) $S(v,p)$ can be computed from $S(v,p-1)$ by finding the sum of integers that are removed while sieving with $p$.
>   An integer is removed in this step if it is the product of $p$ with
>   another integer that has no divisor smaller than $p$. This can be
>   expressed as
>
> $S(v,p)=S(v,p−1)−p(S(\frac{v}{p},p−1)−S(p−1,p−1)).$
>
> Dynamic programming can be used to implement this. It is sufficient to
>   compute $S(v,p)$ for all positive integers $v$ that are representable as
>   $\lfloor \frac{n}{k} \rfloor$ for some integer $k$ and all $p \leq \sqrt{v}$.
>
> Python:
>
> ```
> def P10(n):
>     r = int(n**0.5)
>     assert r*r <= n and (r+1)**2 > n
>     V = [n//i for i in range(1,r+1)]
>     V += list(range(V[-1]-1,0,-1))
>     S = {i:i*(i+1)//2-1 for i in V}
>     for p in range(2,r+1):
>         if S[p] > S[p-1]:  # p is prime
>             sp = S[p-1]  # sum of primes smaller than p
>             p2 = p*p
>             for v in V:
>                 if v < p2: break
>                 S[v] -= p*(S[v//p] - sp)
>     return S[n]
> ```
>
> The complexity of this algorithm is about $O(n^{0.75})$ and needs 9
>   ms to find the solution. Computing the sum of primes up to different
>   bounds $n$ gives:
>
> n = $2 \cdot 10^7$: 12272577818052  0.04 s
>   n = $2 \cdot 10^8$: 1075207199997334  0.2 s
>   n = $2 \cdot 10^9$: 95673602693282040  1 s
>   n = $2 \cdot 10^{10}$: 8617752113620426559  6.2 s
>   n = $2 \cdot 10^{11}$: 783964147695858014236  34 s
>   n = $2 \cdot 10^{12}$: 71904055278788602481894  3 min
>
> I also have a C++ version of this algorithm. This one solves the
>   problem in 700μs. It needs 10 hours to compute the sum of primes up
>   to $10^{17}$ which is 129408626276669278966252031311350.
>
> It is also possible to improve the complexity of the algorithm to
>   $O(n^{2/3})$, but the code would be more complex.

I've checked with pen and Python - according to me, it works as described:

```
>>> P10(2*10**10)
8617752113620426559 in 8 s

>>> P10(2*10**11)
783964147695858014236 in 45 s

>>> P10(2*10**12)
71904055278788602481894 in 3 min 19 s
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try programming a sieve to mark all the composites, then add up the unmarked numbers. To do that, you'll need a list of primes up to $10^7$. In order to get that, you could program a sieve...

This method is obviously pretty memory-intensive, but it's certainly faster than prime-testing each integer from $10^{10}$ to $10^{14}$.