# $\sum p\;$ over consecutive primes $\;p \equiv 3 \pmod 4\;$ is never a square?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

**Prove or disprove that $\;\sum p\;$ over consecutive primes $\;p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, starting from $\,p=3$, is never a square.**

I think it would be useful to examine the modular equation $\;\sum p \equiv x^2 \pmod 4$.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: What makes you think this is true?  How far out have you checked?

Comment: Up to the prime $\,p=161409943$.

Comment: I can't see any reason why you shouldn't get a square this way, though of course that doesn't prove anything.   The only way I could imagine showing it would be to argue that there was always a perfect square close to (but not equal to) each of those sums...but again, I see no way to get a handle on that.

Comment: Have you checked the remainders? $x^2 \pmod{4}$ always yields $0$ or $1$. Whether the sum is multiples of $3 \pmod{4}$.

Comment: I can verify that it's true for primes < 10⁹.

Comment: FWIW, there's a nice algorithm for prime sums in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2283829/207316 But I don't think it can be (easily) modified to only sum 4n+3 primes, since you need both 4n+1 and 4n+3 primes to do the underlying sieving.

Comment: FWIW, for primes $p\equiv1\pmod4$, there are 3 squares in the accumulative sum for $p<10^9$: $$\begin{array}{r|r|r}
p & r & r^2\\
\hline
41 & 12 & 144\\
353 & 76 & 5776\\
4217 & 745 & 555025\\
\end{array}$$

Comment: Checked through 4222138439 ≈ 4x10^9 (which is the 100 millionth prime of the form $4k+3$)

Comment: And here are results for all primes $p<10^8$: $$\begin{array}{r|r|r} p & r & r^2\\ \hline 23 & 10 & 100\\ 22073 & 5063 & 25633969\\ 67187 & 14573 & 212372329\\ 79427 & 17098 & 292341604\\ 10729219 & 1916357 & 3672424151449\\ \end{array}$$ and $2<p<10^8$: $$\begin{array}{r|r|r} p & r & r^2\\ \hline 89 & 31 & 961\\ 107 & 37 & 1369\\ 131 & 43 & 1849\\ 199 & 65 & 4225\\ 1949 & 513 & 263169\\ 52081 & 11442 & 130919364\\ 130729 & 27540 & 758451600\\ \end{array}$$

Comment: Heuristically the expected number of squares between the $10^8$th and $10^{10}$th primes is $1$.  So it could be a significant amount of computation to find an actual example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I conjecture that the sum is a square (rarely but) infinitely often. (Moreover, this has nothing to do with the precise sequence being summed—the conjecture would be the same for any natural sequence growing at the same rate.)

The sum of the first $n$ primes that are congruent to $3$ (mod $4$) is asymptotic to $n^2\log n$. When adding the next such prime, which is about $2n\log n$ in size, we will jump over approximately $\sqrt{\log n}$ squares, which means that the "probability" of landing on a square should be the same as the probability that a randomly chosen number of size about $n^2\log n$ is a square, which is $\frac1{n\sqrt{\log n}}$. Since $\sum \frac1{n\sqrt{\log n}}$ diverges (at a rate of about $2\sqrt{\log n}$, by the integral test), this suggests that there should be infinitely many examples.

Comment: I tried with odd numbers $4k+3$ whose sum is $\sum _{k=1}^n (4 k+3)=2 n^2+5 n$ and find just $2$ cases in the first ten thousands value of $n$, namely $20$ and $720$. The next one is $n=24500$. I am not so optimist for primes, but I can't prove that it doesn't exist. I tried also for $4k+1$ odd (not only prime) numbers and found a similar distribution

Comment: That sounds reasonable, but we may have to go rather high before we get a square, on the order of [Skewe's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewes%27s_number), if not *much* higher. One of the simplest square sum problems, the [cannonball problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannonball_problem) took a while before it was solved by elementary methods. Prime sum squares seem orders of magnitude harder to me, since primes don't play nicely with additive relations; it's hard enough just counting them. ;) Maybe the proof of the RH would shed some light on this problem...

Comment: @PM2Ring That’s a bit overdramatic. The heuristic described in this answer suggests we only need $O(n^2)$ digits to find the $n$th example, so we might find billions of examples before reaching Skewes’ number.  The cannonball problem, while simpler to analyze, is a much sparser sequence than sums of primes, so the expectation there is finite unlike this problem.

Comment: @Erick Ok, maybe I'm being unduly pessimistic, like the original estimate of the Skewes number.

Comment: @PM2Ring Ah, if you’re referring to the precise Skewes’s number (which is less than $10^{317}$). then that’s not too implausible.  I definitely wouldn’t predict more than a few dozen examples up to that number.